# TFS2012 Project Build Priority

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is there a way in TFS 2012 to set Project (not .csproj projects but TFS projects) build priority?

Currently we have many projects in TFS, one of which is a core project that many other projects reference.  If someone checks in changes to both core and another project at once, the core project build doesn't always kick off first (I think they build in alphabetical order).  It would be nice to be able to set the core project as the highest priority so that its build always runs first when changes to multiple projects are checked in.  Is this possible?

Comment: I was actually going to tell you how to correctly set the solution build order, but you seem to be happy with the other answer so I won't worry about it.

Comment: Projects within a solution build fine and correct order and everything.  I was looking for a way to change Build definition order as detailed in the answer I marked correct.  Project was probably a bad choice for asking the question but I didn't know how else to ask it.

Thanks for your input though.

Comment: No problems, but I suspect that setting affinity between a build definition and build agent may not solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set the default build priority for a Build Definition. Since a Build Definition isn't bound to a Team project, but to a collection, there is also no way to configure the Queue to pick up builds from one Team Project before any others.

What you can do is to set a tag on an agent and then assign that tag to the build you want to take precedence. This will exclusively reserve the Build Agent to that specific build definition, causing it to jump in the queue.

Comment: I added a tab to my build agent. But how could i use that Tag in my build definition? Do i have just add that tag at the end of my build definition name? What about all other build definitions, that dont have that tag in them? Are they going to stop working? I want to give other builds priority then our queues CI builds.

Comment: You need at least 2 build agents of which one has the tag. Then in your build definition look up the Agent settings to assign the tag filter.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in TFS 2012 to set Project (not .csproj projects but TFS projects) build priority?

A *project* in TFS is quite a loose term which does not correspond to a VS project, it's actually used to refer to a product which can contain many branches. The high level project management tools then operate on the TFS "project".

> If someone checks in changes to both core and another project at once, the core project build doesn't always kick off first (I think they build in alphabetical order).

Nope, assuming you don't have a custom build then they (the VS projects) don't build in alphabetic order at all, they build in order of dependency. Solutions are built in the order they are returned from the evaluation of the `$(SolutionsToBuild)` property (this does a wildcard search of the filesystem for .sln files, so maybe that's where your alphabetic observation comes from). Note that dependencies are evaluated on projects *within* a solution, there is no evaluation of dependencies *across* solutions.

*For the following statements I'm going to assume that you have standard CI style builds gated upon checkin.*

If a developer checks in *everything* at once then the checkin will happen as an atomic unit of work and the build will commence once the checkin is successfully committed. If this is not your experience then I would suggest that you either have funky stuff happening in a custom build, or the developer is checking blocks of work in separately rather than all at once.

Note that this happens per checkin per workspace - if two different developers check stuff in at the same time then whoever checks-in first will trigger the build, and the submission of the second developer will miss the build.